# Foreach loop to display all records with same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my table `courses` I have several entries that share the same `academy_id`. I am using a foreach loop to retrieve the values in the result set. The for loop only displays one result and not all the others that share the same `academy_id`. How can I display all the rows that share the same `academy_id`?

*Table Values*

```
+----+------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+
| id | academy_id |     course_name      |  start_date   |  end_date  |
+----+------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+
| 1  |        123 | Biology - Basic      | 2013-11-30    | 2013-12-25 |
| 2  |        123 | Biology - Nutrition  | 2013-11-30    | 2013-12-25 |
| 3  |        345 | Chemistry            | 2013-11-30    | 2013-12-25 |
| 4  |        678 | Calculus             | 2013-11-30    | 2013-12-25 |
+----+------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+
```

*PHP*

```
$academy_id = '123';

$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT c.course_name,
       c.course_start_date,
       c.course_end_date
FROM courses c
WHERE c.academy_id = 123
");
if (!$db_select) return false;
    if (!$db_select->execute(array(':academy_id' => $academy_id))) return false;
    $results = $db_select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results)) return false;
    foreach ($results as $value){
    $final_result = "<b>Course Name: </b>".$value['course_name']."</br><b>Start Date: </b>".$value['start_date']."</br><b>End Date: </b>".$value['end_date']."</br>";
    }
print_r($_POST);
}
```

*Curent Result*

```
+----+------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
| id | academy_id |   course_name     |  start_date   |  end_date  |
+----+------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
| 1  |        123 | Biology - Basic   | 2013-11-30    | 2013-12-25 |
+----+------------+-------------------+---------------+------------+
```

*Wanted Result all `academy_id = 123` to show*

```
+----+------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+
| id | academy_id |     course_name      |  start_date   |  end_date  |
+----+------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+
| 1  |        123 | Biology - Basic      | 2013-11-30    | 2013-12-25 |
| 2  |        123 | Biology - Nutrition  | 2013-11-30    | 2013-12-25 |
+----+------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$academy_id = '123';

....

foreach ($results as $value){
    $final_result = "<b>Course Name: </b>".$value['course_name']."</br><b>Start Date: </b>".$value['start_date']."</br><b>End Date: </b>".$value['end_date']."</br>";
}
```

for

```
$academy_id = 123;

.....

$final_result = '';
foreach ($results as $value){
    $final_result .= "<b>Course Name: </b>".$value['course_name']."</br><b>Start Date: </b>".$value['start_date']."</br><b>End Date: </b>".$value['end_date']."</br>";
}

echo $final_result;
```

Comment: That doesnt change anything. The select echo `$final_result` only displays one result with `$academy_id = 123` and not the second result

Answer (score 0):

(seeing other people's answer I know mine resolves a different question you had or might have had)
I am not sure I fully understand your request, but here is something you can try

Split your code into two parts

1) Part one will do:

```
SELECT c.academy_id
FROM courses c
GROUP BY c.academy_id
```

This will be your primary results for the loop

2) Part two inside the previous loop will do your current SQL but instead of hardcoded 123, it will use the result of the previous query as the value